# hamburger dropdown css display property

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a CSS media query / flexbox style that assigns a "display: none" to a navigation div after it goes to the max-width of 768px. Using Javascript, I was able to toggle display: "block"  and "none" using an if/else statement once my hamburger button is pressed.

However, the pain point is that once I toggle it to "display: none", the navbar is now gone once the screen is beyond the designated width; and hamburger menu only appears at the smaller width size.

It seems like the toggle permanently assigns "display: none" to it. How would I remove the "display: none" back to "display: block" without clicking on hamburger button?

```js
const burgerBar = document.querySelector('.burger');
const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation');
const navbarItems = document.querySelector('.navbar-items');
const navbarItem = document.querySelector('.navbar-item');

burgerBar.addEventListener('click', () => {

  if (navigation.style.display != 'block') {
    navigation.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    navigation.style.display = 'none'
  }


})
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* width below 768 */
  .header-container {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .navigation {
    display: none;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <nav class="navbar-container">
    <ul class="navbar-items">
      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="/">Github</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="/">About</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="burger">
  <div class="bar-one"></div>
  <div class="bar-two"></div>
  <div class="bar-three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `window.onresize`:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp ?

Comment: Can you also include your HTML so we can test this? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks Team! Just added HTML part that those are aimed for. Let me know what you think / how else to improve. Im trying to avoid tutorial videos since most aim for the translate / transformX/Y 100% .. doesn't really help my cause.

Comment: In addition to window.onresize, you can just set a media query that has a display: block; for any size over the small size, so when you move to a larger screen it auto inherits the display: block;

Comment: Hi Robin - tried just doing that as well at max-width of 1200px to see.. and my display:none; unfortunately is still attached to the navigation div because of how I applied the property via javascript I think? I checked using inspector at the larger size and "style='display:none'" is still attached. Digging still!

Comment: Can you update the snippet to fix the `burgerBar is undefined`? You're missing the variable to define what `burgerBar` is.

Comment: Got it - Just added the queryselectors for burgerBar and the rest. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing with javascript is using inline-styles for the tag itself
for eaxmple

`navigation.style.display = 'block'`

will make it like this

`<div style="display:none;"> </div>`

but what you are doing with css using classes can't override the inline-styles
due to [CSS Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)

> Every selector has its place in the specificity hierarchy. There are
> four categories which define the specificity level of a selector:
>
> **Inline styles** - An inline style is attached directly to the element to
> be styled. Example: .
>
> **IDs** - An ID is a unique identifier for the page elements, such as
> #navbar.
>
> **Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes** - This category includes
> .classes, [attributes] and pseudo-classes such as :hover, :focus etc.
>
> **Elements and pseudo-elements** - This category includes element names
> and pseudo-elements, such as h1, div, :before and :after.

**solution:**

use javascript to toggle a class (instead of changing the property directly) that hides the navigation

Comment: funny.. I just tried that using navigation.classList.add('display_toggle') (just created that class with only display:block;. I see it applied after cllicking but it doesn't override the media query display:none; property. i just see the class stick there.

Comment: is the new class after the mediaQuery or before ?

Comment: after the media query is applied, since the burger only appears at 768px or lower. At that point, the navigation div has a display:none; assigned to it. Then javascript executes after i click the burger button that appears. I guess it doesnt overrite the media query property that was assigned =[

Answer (score 0):

solved! The display_toggle class need to be after the media query...I believe that has something to do with specificity that.